# how to put commas in text file

Tags: command-line

I have text file having name like this:

```
map_leaf_M_BAN.AC.txt   
map_leaf_M_BAN.A.txt    
map_leaf_M_BAN.C.txt    
map_leaf_M_BAR.AC.txt
```

I need these name in text file like this

```
map_leaf_M_BAN.AC.txt,map_leaf_M_BAN.A.txt,map_leaf_M_BAN.C.txt,map_leaf_M_BAR.AC.txt
```

Please suggest How I can do this?

Kind regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758814/turning-multiple-lines-into-one-line-with-comma-separated-perl-sed-awk

Answer (score 3):

If you have the names in a text file (`names.txt`) already, you just want to replace all newlines with commas:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\s*\n/,/' names.txt 
map_leaf_M_BAN.AC.txt,map_leaf_M_BAN.A.txt,map_leaf_M_BAN.C.txt,map_leaf_M_BAR.AC.txt,$
```

But that still needs a final newline and has an extra comma in the end. So remove those with:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\s*\n/,/' names.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/'
map_leaf_M_BAN.AC.txt,map_leaf_M_BAN.A.txt,map_leaf_M_BAN.C.txt,map_leaf_M_BAR.AC.txt
```

And, to save this in a new file, just redirect the output:

```
perl -pe 's/\s*\n/,/' names.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/' > newFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ls *txt | paste -s -d, > newFile.txt
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been downvoted; it seems to me to be a more-or-less valid attempt to answer a slightly different interpretation of the OP's *"I have text file having name like this"*

Comment: Dunno. There's nothing in the question about "sed only answer", and you don't even need to have the names inside a txt file.

Comment: Arguably `ls * | ...` is bad practice because it will be subject to word splitting; for the filenames in the OP that's not an issue but a more general solution would probably be something like `printf '%s\0' *txt | paste -zs -d,` (which makes everything in the pipeline null-delimited)